# How do I root my 4G LG Motion?

Tags: rooting, lg-motion

How do I root my 4G LG Motion? I have an app that needs root access, but I don't know how to root my phone. Also, I REALLY want this app so.... If you know please help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OneClickRoot](http://www.oneclickroot.com/phone/lg-motion-4g/), their tool is supposed to work for the *LG Motion 4G*. You can [download the tool](http://www.oneclickroot.com/download-now/) from their site, and they even offer a "remote rooting service". In addition to that tool, you will need the appropriate drivers for your device, which you can e.g. find [here](http://www.lg-phones.org/lg-motion-4g-ms770-usb-driver-download.html). Having that installed, it should be as easy as: Start the tool, connect your device, click to root.

Another rooting guide is offered by [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/motion-4g-all-things-root/611262-guide-howto-root-lg-motion-4g.html) (the article links all software needed, including the drivers), which uses the [O4X tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818502) from the XDA developers (I used this succesfully on my O4X -- seems like it also works on your Motion 4G). Steps included are also pretty easy: Having installed the drivers, unpacked O4X, and the additional *IS11LG_SystemBackupTest.signed.apk* from the XDA post, you go to *Settings→Security* on your Motion, and tick [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources). In *Settings→Developer Options* you enable [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging). Then you install and open `IS11LG_SystemBackupTest.signed.apk`, and finally restart your device. Once phone turns back on (should be running slow) connect your phone to your computer through USB (charging only). Open the command prompt and enter `cd C:\o4xr`, then type `root`. Next wait for the script to run and your phone will reboot; when that happens uninstall the *SystemBackupTest* app. **DO NOT OPEN IT**, or you will have to repeat the entire procedure :)